# span pushes the adjacent span down

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<span class="symbol">$</span>
<span class="value">400</span>
```

This displays both "$" and "400" at the same level.

The moment I add

**CSS**

```
.symbol {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

then, "400" is pushed down.

Question: Why is "400/`.value`" affected by changes to "$/`.symbol`" ?

Thanks.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emLLrm

Comment: **vertical-align:middle;**??

Comment: Where do you want the **$** vs 400?

Comment: use vertical-align:middle for .symbol

Comment: The default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question realistically is about vertically aligning, and can be solved using

```
vertical-align:middle
```

or

```
vertical-align:top;
```

to override the default baseline (which by default is set to the bottom).

---

**Demo:**

```css
.symbol {
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="symbol">$</span>
<span class="value">400</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not clear - why is "400" pushed down ? For e.g. if I wrap both "$" and "400" with a `div` initially, then both their `vertical-align` is `top`. And then, after I change the `font-size` of "$" to 2, then why is "400"  suddenly not `vertical-align:top` ?

Comment: span (amongst many others) are defaulted to bottom (so think of 'they're aligned along the bottom of the div's top line' if that makes sence). I'll post another situation with divs in a sec to show this.

Comment: @KayaToast: Here's that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/k4y8zasn/ - see how they seem to be aligned to top? try hovering one of them (where I change their height). See? Same issue. Adding vertical-align: top to the div will 'fix' this

Comment: but why are the spans initially aligned to the top (when they are wrapped in a div, whose `height` > `line-height` of `.value/.symbol`) ? i'm not being difficult, i genuinely want to understand the concept

Comment: @KayaToast: default settings. spans have a baseline set to bottom, divs are set to top. Think of specificity: so the div will force eveerything to the 'first line' (which is set by default to top), so span is at the top. However, think of span being only a small height - only enough for a single line in fact - and so within this 'span' element, the text is actually aligned to the bottom (only you can't see this as it's a single line)

Comment: [Updated fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/k4y8zasn/1/)

Comment: This question is a duplicate (didn't know it had to do with inline-blocks) ... and your above comment aligns with spec/explanation from the other/original questions. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you want more control over the positioning in relation to the number, use `position:relative` and `top:` on the symbol to position where you'd like.  For instance:

```
.symbol {
font-size: 2em;
position:relative;
top: .3em; /* or 10px if you want to use pixels */
}
```